# Docker - Prevent updating some files on the server with new docker build

Tags: docker, logging, dockerfile

On my server access logs are created at /var/log/apache2/access.log and all access logs are here. After i build new image and upload to server these logs are removed. Is there any way to persist the old access.log file and just append to it with the new build.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mount a volume to write the logs to, they will persist between instances.

The simplest thing would be to mount `/var/log/apache2`, but you should think about multiple instances.

https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/